# static variables in web site and web application C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7

I have same codes which work differently on 2 different IIS servers which one is set as web site and another is set as web application.

I have 2 classes.

```
public class Config1{
    public static string RelativePath {get; set;}
}

public class Config2{
    public static readonly string FavIconPath = Config1.RelativePath;
}
```

And I assign value from web.config in Global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_Start(){
    Config1.RelativePath = getWebConfigValue("Path");
}
```

I use it in view files like below.

```
RelativePath : @Config1.RelativePath<p/>
FavIconPath : @Config2.FavIconPath
```

The results are

```
On web site server
RelativePath : somevalue
FavIconPath : 

On web application server
RelativePath : somevalue
FavIconPath : somevalue
```

Is there any differences of instantiate timing between web site and web application? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Static field initializers such as the one assigning the initial value to `Config2.FavIconPath` are processed when the type (`Config2`) is first referenced. This typically happens when *your code* first accesses it, but it may happen sooner.

The value of `Config1.RelativePath` changes after the `Application_Start()` method is called, so the actual value used for the `FavIconPath` depends on the order of the `Application_Start()` method and the `Config2` type to be loaded.

Even though I don't know what happens under the hood, this code shows why you should not let code depend on framework internal behavior.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought too, so I assumed there might be some timing differences to call Application_Start() between web site and web application.